# Nant build time set

Tags: nant

Does anybody know how to set the build time on NANT project script?
Actually I want NANT to run the project at some specific time like every night at 8pm(Nightly Build).
How can I set this time?

Answer (score 2):

Set up the nant command to run as a scheduled task* under the control panel.

*Or a cron job if you're using Mono.

Comment: Or use a build server running CruiseControl.NET (or some other build running tool) to make things easier when you have more than one machine or more than one project.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your ccnet.config file to have CruiseControl .net run your build project at given day.time:

```
<scheduleTrigger time="23:30" buildCondition="ForceBuild">
     <weekDays>
        <weekDay>Monday</weekDay>
        <weekDay>Tuesday</weekDay>
        <weekDay>Wednesday</weekDay>
        <weekDay>Thursday</weekDay>
        <weekDay>Friday</weekDay>
        <weekDay>Saturday</weekDay>
    </weekDays>
</scheduleTrigger>
```

As the code suggests, this will force the build event to take place Mon-Sat after 23:30 each day.

Any good?

Answer (score 0):

you cant do that using nant. simple way to create a simple batch script(it will trigger your nant script) and run that from Windows Task Scheduler at your desired time